# end and start new UL every 10 mysql results

Tags: php, mysql, html-lists

all i want to do is end the current, and begin a new UL every 10 results

heres my code which isn't working 100%:

```
    $sql1 = mysql_query("select * from `provinces` order by `name` asc");

    while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql1))
    {
        echo '<li id="popup_'.strtolower(str_replace(' ', '_', $row1['name'])).'">';
        echo '<ul>';

        $sql2 = mysql_query("select * from `cities` where `id_province`='".$row1['id']."' order by `name` asc");
        $count = 1;

        while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql2))
        {
            if ($count % 10 == 0)
                echo '</ul>';

            echo '<li>'.$row2['name'].'</li>';

            if ($count % 10 == 0)
                echo '<ul>';

            $count++;
        }

        echo '</ul>';
        echo '</li>';
    }
```

Comment: You need to rewrite your queries it can be combined into one

Comment: @lbu: there aren't any differences with or without those ( )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

replace this

```
if ($count % 10 == 0)
       echo '</ul>';
```

with

```
    if ($count % 10 == 0)
            echo '</ul><ul>';
```

And completly remove the second check

```
        if ($count % 10 == 0)
            echo '<ul>';
```

Otherwise your html screws up

// took me some time to get this answered because the problem was not easy to indentify :)

Comment: you rock. i knew it was something simple.

Answer (score -1):

so it should work with new ul AFTER 10 results... if you want it BEFORE every 10th result you have to set the if block before the li output

```
$sql1 = mysql_query("select * from `provinces` order by `name` asc");

    while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql1))
    {
        echo '<li id="popup_'.strtolower(str_replace(' ', '_', $row1['name'])).'">';
        echo '<ul>';

        $sql2 = mysql_query("select * from `cities` where `id_province`='".$row1['id']."' order by `name` asc");
        $count = 1;

        while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql2))
        {
            echo '<li>'.$row2['name'].'</li>';
            if ($count % 10 == 0)
                echo '</ul><ul>';
            $count++;
        }

        echo '</ul>';
        echo '</li>';
    }
```